# Trying to search for follow up questions in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that will search through a transcript of a call between a marketer and a customer. The code scans through the transcript line by line searching for a phrase specified in an external txt file, if it finds a match, it prints the entire line the match is on, followed by the next line, which is the response.

I've developed a bit of code that will identify if 'yes' has been said to one question, which will lead to more follow up questions, however, I cannot get it to loop through the rest of the script searching for these follow up questions after the line?

Could anyone give me a hand?

I have the following code:

```
with open ('/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/untitled folder/untitled folder/transcribe.txt') as my_new_file:
    contents = my_new_file.read()

partner_file = open('/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/untitled folder/untitled folder/P.txt')

with open('/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/untitled folder/untitled folder/follow_up_question.txt') as follow_up_question_file:
    follow_up = follow_up_question_file.read()

partners = partner_file.readlines()
# Converts it to a list
lines = contents.split("\n")
follow_up_list = follow_up.split("\n")
for p in partners:
    try:
        output = None
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                if p.strip() in line:
                    output = index
                    break
        if output:
            print ("\n" + lines[output] + "\n")
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("\n" + lines[output +1] + "\n")
            if "yes" in lines[output +1].lower() or "yeah" in lines[output + 1].lower():
                print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
                print ("\n" + lines[output +2] + "\n")
                try:
                    for follow in follow_up_list():
                        if follow in lines[output+2].lower():
                            True
                        print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
                        print ("\n" + lines[output +3] + "\n")
                        break
                except (ValueError):
                    print("Nothing found")
                    break
    except:
        pass
```

An example of my transcript can be found here:

https://paste.pythondiscord.com/obucaweyuc.py

My p.txt can be found here:

> have you spoken with a ARM partner in the last six months

And my follow_up_questions.txt has:

> did you talk about similar issues?

However the current output only displays:

> ch_0 :  have you spoken with a ARM partner in the last six months
>   about having a discussion about how ARM those,  um,  quality
>   security could benefit you guys?
>
> ---
>
> ch_1 :  Yeah, we have
>
> ---
>
> ch_0 : Oh, okay and did you talk about similar issues?

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is the following line of "oh, okay and did you talk about similar issues?" followed by more follow up questions after the first question "have you spoken with a ARM partner in the last six months..."

Comment: @OwenMurray how is this different from your previous question ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers My previous question was about the response not being printed, while similar, this is in response to the loop issue I am having.

Comment: @OwenMurray ok sorry didn't spot this. I reopened the question and apologize for the inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned up your code a bit just to try to simplyfy the problem. I have included the output it produces, as per your comment it gives the line after

```py
with open('transcribe.txt') as t_file, open('p.txt') as p_file, open('follow_up_question.txt') as f_file:
    t_lines = t_file.readlines()
    f_lines = f_file.readlines()
    p_lines = p_file.readlines()
    for p_line in p_lines:
        for index, line in enumerate(t_lines):
            if p_line.strip() in line:
                print(f'{t_lines[index]}{"-"*30}\n{t_lines[index + 1]}', end='')
                if "yes" in t_lines[index + 1].lower() or "yeah" in t_lines[index + 1].lower():
                    print(f'{"-"*30}\n{t_lines[index + 2]}', end='')
                    for follow in f_lines:
                        if follow in t_lines[index + 2].lower():
                            print(f'{"-"*30}\n{t_lines[index + 3]}', end='')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ch_0 :  have you spoken with a ARM partner in the last six months about having a discussion about how ARM those,  um,  quality security could benefit you guys? 
------------------------------
ch_1 :  Yes, we have
------------------------------
ch_0 : Oh, okay and did you talk about similar issues?
------------------------------
ch_0 :  Okay,  Uh,  would you be willing to,  um,  have a discussion with ARM partner?  Um,  it's project making business sense
```

However just for your reference the issue in your code was this line

`for follow in follow_up_list():`

follow_up_list is a python list and is not callable so you need to drop the parentheses

`for follow in follow_up_list:`

Comment: Thank you very much for that! However, when I change the transcript to the one in my original post, it doesn't print anything? (The transcript in the post has the actual client's name redacted from it)

Comment: I understand the need to redact client details but its hard to say why it wouldnt work when you change to the original transcript. Code, is code, it will iterate over the file and assuming the partner name is in the p file and that same name is in the transcription file i dont see any reason why it wouldnt work

Comment: Apologies, I made an extremely simple error and did not replace the redacted names. That is fantastic! However, it still stops looking for follow up questions after one has been answered? The last one that gets picked up is the question that follows immediately after they say "Yes" to the first question, but there could be many more follow up questions asked, is it possible to do this?

Comment: its possible to do anything with a clear description of the problem and the expected requirement. But how do you go on to identify the remaiing follow up questions. because your logic is for each partner, loop over the lines in the transcript till you find the partner name. then look on the next line for the word yes or yeah then for the next line look for each follow up question(its checking for each follow up question on the same line). So in your current program design this wont work.

Comment: So currently the script is looking for a specific question rather than a partner, the question possibilities are "have you spoken with a [company] partner?" or "has a [company] partner reached out to you in the last six months" etc, if the customer replies "no" then it stops there, if the customer says "yes", then it will loop through all follow up questions in the txt file and get the response for them all if they are present